Does file_get_contents() issue http requests when given an url leading to the same server?
if I pass an url to file_get_contents() (svg in my case), does it cause an http request? Or just because it will be compiled server site, it does not?
And what is I pass a local path instead of a url?
Essentially, I want to know if, by using it several times on a web page, it's going to slow it down, even if very little.

Ah by the way, it seems I cannot start my question with Hi, or Hello, because when I save it they get cutted out. So Hello you all!

Check the docs: https://www.php.net/file_get_contents
Yes, you can pass in a URL. Yes, http://example.com will be an HTTP request. Yes, it will add that time to your page load.

They do not explicitly answer to my question.

it seems I cannot start my question with Hi, or Hello...yes because that's  superfluous text. You just need to ask your question. We expect people to be basically polite, but you don't need to clutter your post with chit-chat or irrelevant conversation.

But yes if you pass in a URL, the function will make a HTTP GET request to that URL. If you pass in a file path, it will ask the O/S to open that file. The file_get_contents docs aren't completely explicit about this, but it's pretty obvious from the examples, and also the supported protocols and wrappers document which is linked from the main doc does mention it more clearly, as does the HTTP wrapper doc which is linked from there. So yes the documentation does tell you, if you look hard enough

Essentially, I want to know if, by using it several times on a web page, it's going to slow it down, even if very little...this is not directly relevant to your original question. HTTP is probably, on balance, going to be slightly slower than fileystem access. So if you have the choice (i.e. the file is on the same server as the PHP script) then it would make more sense to use the filesystem path to access it - HTTP adds a slight overhead. But obviously if the file is located elsewhere then you don't have the choice. Whether the request is slow or not depends on many other factors of course.

Note that you need the allow_url_fopen setting enabled (which it is by default) in order for file_get_contents() to make HTTP requests. If you use it several times, it will make several HTTP requests.

@ADyson it is. In essence, they are asking, would PHP somehow magically recognize that an url provided leads to the same server, and convert an HTTP call into a local filesystem call. Given PHP wouldn't do anything like that and HTTP call takes more resources, using URLs instead of local paths makes your page to run slower

Basically I don't see how this question makes any sense. This is like asking "Can i use a shovel to dig"?

@YourCommonSense I think that's probably what they mean, but it's not explicitly stated in the question. So if the question is "is using HTTP or filesystem faster for loading the same file" then it's certainly true (as I said) that the filesystem access would be faster. But the question could be interpreted as "is HTTP or filesystem faster (in general)" - in which case it would depend on what you're loading, and from where, and how big it is etc etc.  I agree it's a fairly poor question.

If the argument is a URL, it will use the appropriate protocol to fetch it. If the URL begins with http: or https: it will issue an HTTP request; if it begins with ftp: it will issue an FTP request. See Supported Protocols and Wrappers for the complete list.
This assumes that the allow_url_fopen option is enabled in php.ini (as it is by default).
If it's an ordinary pathname, the file will be accessed directly from the local filesystem, subject to restriction by the open_basename setting.
Most functions that take a filename argument work like this, although some cannot work with all URL schemes because the protocol doesn't support that feature (e.g. you can't get stat() information using HTTP).
